# Nagios download report

Tags: shell, cmd, nagios

I'm trying to download the report through shell cmds, after some tutorials i got:

```
wget -v –user 'nagUser' –password '.C|n#q.U$#r' –no-check-certificate -O report.html "http://[IP]/nagios/cgi-bin/avail.cgi?show_log_entries=&hostgroup=all&timeperiod=lastweek"
```

but I got the following error:

```
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://xn--user-z86a/
Resolving –user (xn--user-z86a)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--user-z86a’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://xn--user-z86a/
Resolving –user (xn--user-z86a)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--user-z86a’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://nagUser/
Resolving nagUser(nagUser)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘nagUser’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://xn--password-rn3d/
Resolving –password (xn--password-rn3d)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--password-rn3d’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://xn--password-rn3d/
Resolving –password (xn--password-rn3d)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--password-rn3d’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://.c%7Cn/
Resolving .c|n (.c|n)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘.c|n’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://xn--no-check-certificate-2t2l/
Resolving –no-check-certificate (xn--no-check-certificate-2t2l)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--no-check-certificate-2t2l’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://xn--no-check-certificate-2t2l/
Resolving –no-check-certificate (xn--no-check-certificate-2t2l)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--no-check-certificate-2t2l’
--2017-04-27 09:23:05--  http://[IP]/nagios/cgi-bin/avail.cgi?show_log_entries=&hostgroup=all&timeperiod=lastweek
Connecting to [IP]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-04-27 09:23:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

maybe I'm missing an argument?

Comment: You may need to escape the VERTICAL BAR `|` character. What happens if you use `'.C^|n#q.U$#r'`?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of suffering I managed to download the report following these steps:

- Include de IP in the hosts file configuration `[IP] [URL Name]`
- Use an URL insted of the IP (weird but true)
- cmd: `wget -q --user='nagiosUser' --password='nagiosPassword' --no-check-certificate -O [fileName.ext] "[report link]"`
- report link: `http://[URL]/nagios/cgi-bin/avail.cgi?show_log_entries=&host=all&timeperiod=[TIMEPERIOD]&rpttimeperiod=&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestateretention=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&includesoftstates=no&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&backtrack=4&csvoutput=`

Note the `'` encapsulating user and password, also no spaces between `--user='user'` same for password, there is no need to scape especial characters. And `"` for the link. Also I use `-q` for quiet mode, otherwise `-v` verbouse.

I wanted the output report as csv file so note `&csvoutput=` in the link, otherwise it would download it as `HTML`

These are the valid Time Periods:
    today        => Today

```
last24hours  => Last 24 hours
yesterday    => Yesterday
thisweek     => This week
last7days    => Last 7 days
lastweek     => Last week
thismonth    => This month
last31days   => Last 31 days
lastmonth    => Last month (default)
thisyear     => This year
lastyear     => Last year
```